# Detecting Element Type for Positioned Images

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am trying to go through each element in Google doc. When I get to positioned images I am having trouble locating the image so I can handle processing it with my apps script.

There is no elementtype for positioned image so I am unable to pass it when I break down the doc element by element. Heres the Inline Image detector

```
if (itemType === DocumentApp.ElementType.INLINE_IMAGE) {
    returns true if inlineImage detected
}
```

Is there anyway to do this for Positioned Images? such as:

```
if (itemType === DocumentApp.ElementType.POSITIONED_IMAGE) {
    returns true if PositionedImage detected
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample Document for understanding your situation? It will help users think of your solution. Of course, please remove your personal information from the sample document.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the getPositionedImages() method from the paragraph/list classes. This pulls a list of images anchored to the paragraph/list.

So my code end up looking like

```
if( item.getPositionedImages() !== null){
     //Process Image
}
```